# Page scrolling on its own with jQuery .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have the below code on a page and if you try to scroll it pulls back and starts scrolling to the top of the page.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

   // Initially hide the elements
   $('.first-div, .second-div').hide();

   $('.filter-link').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.first-div, .second-div').slideToggle();
      $(this).html($(this).html() == '<i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide Filters' ? '<i class="far fa-eye"></i> Show Filters' : '<i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide Filters');
      return false;
    });
});
```

If I remove the first line in function that initially hides the divs it doesn't do it anymore. Could anyone help with what it could be please?

Comment: Is there any error or warning in the console ? Code seems to be finde on the first look. Why do you toggle two elements instead of wrapping them into one?

Comment: is it not returning any error in console? It should return `cannot read property preventDefault of undefined` as `event` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: There's no console errors. I've now passed event as a parameter in the function but that sadly made no difference either :( I'm at a total loss.

Comment: How does the above code relate to scrolling the page?

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't. In fact no code on the website does. But if I remove the line that initially hides the div it doesn't do it.